# phpmailer cannot post error

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to set up a simple form that sends an email to a user using phpmailer. When I submit the form, I receive an error that says "Cannot POST /public/mail_handler.php". I'm not sure where this is arising from. Here is the html:

```
<title> Schedule an Appointment - Name </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/script.js"></script>
```

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page.html"> Home </a><br>
    <br>
    <li><a class="active" href=""> Appointment </a> <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="specsPage.html"> Build </a> <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="contactPage.html"> Contact </a> <br> 
    <br>
</ul>

<div id="schedulePage">
    <h4> Schedule an Appointment </h4>

    <div id="fullForm">

        <form id="appt" action="public/mail_handler.php" method="POST">

            First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name..."> <br>
            <br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name..."> <br>
            <br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..."> <br>
            <br>
            Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Callback Number..."> <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the php code:

```
<?php

$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;


require("public/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "localhost:4000";  

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  

$mail->Username = "send_from_PHPMailer@name";  // hidden
$mail->Password = "pass"; // hidden

$mail->From = $email;

$mail->AddAddress("test@gmail.com", "Test Account");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Your appointment details.";


if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: check with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` . can you see any errors?

Comment: I cannot seem to locate the php.ini file when I do this.

Comment: Addition: when I refresh the page on the error screen, it now says it has a "GET" request error.